# Wordpress point to static html page

Tags: wordpress

I have a static html coming soon page inside a folder.

1. How to temporary set the wordpress homepage point to this html template folder?
2. How to temporary set all of the wordpress page point to this html template folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiers way is to use a [wordpress plugin for a coming soon page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-coming-soon-page/) that support html code and post your code there, why to make a hack to display everywhere an html page in a wordpress site when you can do it with a simple plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If you put this line at the top of the .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

It will swap the order in which Apache prioritises the files.