# Open .html file in WordPress website

Tags: html, wordpress

I have WordPress website in which I uploaded "popup-menu.html" file which is in .html format.

When I visit url "http://testproject.co/projects2015/prismic_new/wordpress/popup-menu.html" is shows 404 error.

I uploaded HTML file into my theme directory. I think I should have upload it to my root directory, but will that work?

I am curious why I am not able to see that file. There is something I am ignoring or don't know about WordPress. Please help me with that.

Comment: Hi Nizam, what you mean you uploaded "popup-menu.html" file, as in WordPress we create pages as it is CMS.

Comment: @Mohsin I am aware, for some strange reason I want to show that HTML file.

Comment: Wordpress rewrites the url-structure if you call the .html directly over the domain. What you can do to render your html: create a new page over the wordpress dashboard, create a page template where you include your html and then assign that template to your newly created page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress point to static html page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890002/wordpress-point-to-static-html-page)

Comment: I see. It is static file you want WordPress to have nothing to do? right? then simply uploading in the root directory should work as htaccess of WP will not effect if filename or foldername is present.

Comment: @NizamKazi can you share your .htaccess file is it standard WordPress file or custom redirects there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have a static , non WordPress file on your server you can have it on the root directory , just as another file, and can easily access it from the URL . WordPress will not interfere with that url.

WordPress .htaccess will not try to implement its redirect rules on any FILE or FOLDER which exists on main root folder or anywhere.

So if e.g. you need /static.html , you can safely upload it on your root folder with the same name and can access from your browser, WordPress will have nothing to do with it.

You do not need to put it in themes folder as you have done in the start.

Comment: @Nizam Thank you for choosing my answer! Glad I was any help!

Answer (score 0):

Go through following steps:

1. Make sure your web server is pointing to correct directory for popup-menu.html. If not correct it.
2. Open FTP Client and connect to your server. Navigate to the file’s location
   Verify that the file exists. If it is does not exist, you have found the source of your 404.
3. Navigate to: WordPress Dashboard → Settings → Permalinks: Click “Save Changes”. Test your URL. If the 404 goes away, something caused an issue with your permalink structure and this fixed it.

Comment: when I use absolute path for e.g. wp-content/themes/theme-name/file-name.html, it is working perfect. but I don't want to use that url. any solution?

Comment: Why you are uploading it inside themes brother! Just upload it in root folder where wp-content folder and wp-config files are.. WordPress should not have anything to do with it. Or you want something to do with WordPress also?

Comment: @Mohsin I got your point, as I uploaded this file in theme folder. Thanks for the enlightening answer. Post your answer separately so I can vote.

Comment: @NizamKazi Posted my answer! Thanks for your feedback glad it was solved.