# How to run Nuxtjs inside wordpress directory

Tags: wordpress, nuxt.js

Does anybody know how I can run a nuxt app inside a wordpress directory? the public_html contains all wp folders and I added a folder called 'profile' then I paste all nuxt dist inside of it, the problem is, everytime I access domain.com/profile/*any-slug* it returns 404, but on my local, nuxt app is working fine.

Comment: Hi, did you add the [router.base](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/#base) to your `nuxt.config.js` file? In your case, `base: 'profile'`?

Comment: yes, I already did, but still no luck. :( do i need to modify htaccess of wordpress or some sort?

Answer (score 0):

In the dist folder you have an index.html that is like static file.

So

"If you need to have a static , non WordPress file on your server you can have it on the root directory , just as another file, and can easily access it from the URL . WordPress will not interfere with that url.

WordPress .htaccess will not try to implement its redirect rules on any FILE or FOLDER which exists on main root folder or anywhere.

If e.g. you need /static.html , you can safely upload it on your root folder with the same name and can access from your browser, WordPress will have nothing to do with it.

You do not need to put it in themes folder as you have done in the start. "

[Open .html file in WordPress website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054577/open-html-file-in-wordpress-website)

Comment: I don't have index.html on my dist folder because my structure is pages > _slug > index.vue

Comment: If your are in SPA mode and run "npm run generate" then it creates a dist folder that have index.html in it !

Comment: yes it will if you have a default index.vue inside pages, mine dont, im trying to do dynamic routes with no default view. thats why I only have index.vue inside _slug folder